# testNG Maven problem

Tags: ant, maven, dependencies, testng

I am trying to run a build file using Ant. I am using Maven for dependencies. I am having a testNG dependency in my project.

This is the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>be.anova.abis</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pom</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My first Maven POM</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>  
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

The maven downloads the testNG from mavenrepository, but I am getting an error, it is complaining that it can not find org.testng.Assert and org.testng.annotations.Test. (as below)

```
Compiling 10 source files to /home/shahin/Files/Development/Ant/ServiceEJBSample3/bin
    [javac] /home/shahin/Files/Development/Ant/ServiceEJBSample3/ejbModule/net/company/test/Service1Test.java:5: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] /home/shahin/Files/Development/Ant/ServiceEJBSample3/ejbModule/net/company/test/Service1Test.java:6: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /home/shahin/Files/Development/Ant/ServiceEJBSample3/ejbModule/net/company/test/Service1Test2.java:5: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
```

If I don't use maven and simply use ant and specify the location where the testNG.jar file is, there is no problem at all. I have used the same .jar file that maven downloaded for Ant to make sure I am using the same source. I also have tried different versions of testNG from maevnrepo. Any insights ?

Do I need to include all dependencies (all different packages? like org.testng.Assert and org.testng.annotationsTest and as such) in the POM file? or just the one is enough? If I need to have all of them listed in POM file, what is the best and fastet way of doing it?

Comment: The error output looks like it is from Ant but you say it builds fine with Ant. Can you describe what command you are executing to run the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned the maven and revised the build.xml file once again, it works now. Probably it was something wrong in the repository. Thanks all for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.  Did you do a mvn clean first?  Maybe the dependency isn't getting downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your pom.xml looks correct, maybe your repository got corrupt somehow, I suggest `rm -rf ~/.m2` or if you don't want to download the entire Internet, start by just removing the TestNG dependencies only.